# "You can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor."

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2003

I get that error double-clicking this file on Win 2003:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\Back Office Copier\DsDriver]
"printDuplexSupported"=hex:01
"printStaplingSupported"=hex:01
```

I'm confused, since this is just a pared-down export.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you pare out?

Comment: @AthomSfere, A bunch of settings specific to this computer that I don't want to transfer to other computers.  I only want the two settings above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What editor are you using? 
That looks like a legitimate reg file, but if you saved it in something other than Notepad you might have inadvertently added extra formatting codes.

Comment: Textpad, and it's saved as Unicode.

Comment: Save as (Windows/DOS) ASCII. It works fine on my Win7 and Win 2003 machines.

Comment: TextPad didn't have an ASCII option but it did have ANSI, and that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem as well - I had read to make sure it started with `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` and that it was saved in ASCII or UTF-16 LE (Little Endian), but was still getting the error.

As it was though, I had a blank line before the 'Windows Registry' header - so I tried deleting that and it worked.

Comment: +1.   Why the downvotes?   This answer is what got me working, without the stated prefix, the file is not recognized as a registry file by the reg editor.

Answer (score -2):

This question is answered in the following article
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-specified-file-not-registry-script-cannot-import-file-regedit/

Comment: Please add the segment of the article that answers the question directly in the answer.